# PHP search result highlight script

Tags: php, highlight

So let's say I make a search on my website for "Tales of an Ancient Empire".
My database is doing a full text search, and results come up. I have this function for the highlight thngy

```
function sublinhamos($text, $words) {

    // explode the phrase in words
    $wordsArray = explode(' ', $words); 

    // loop all searched words
    foreach($wordsArray as $word) {
        //highlight
        $text = str_ireplace($word, "<span class=\"highlight\">".strtoupper($word)."</span>", $text, $count);
    } 
    //right trows results
    return $text;
}
```

It's not too bad, but the problem here is because the seach terms is "Tales of an Ancient Empire", when the str_ireplace finds the already inserted SPAN's it encounters the "an" words from the search term, and break the SPAN tag.

I need the highlight to highlight parts of a word, and all words up to two characters minimum, but it's all good apart from the old SPAN encounter problem.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, to start I wouldn't use a span.

```
<mark></mark>
```

is the better element to use. It's purpose is for highlighting parts of text like this. See [this article](http://html5doctor.com/draw-attention-with-mark/) for more information.

Also, you can pass an array into str_replace, eg:

```
function sublinhamos($text, $words) {
    $wordsArray = array();
    $markedWords = array();
    // explode the phrase in words
    $wordsArray = explode(' ', $words); 

    foreach ($wordsArray as $k => $word) {
      $markedWords[$k]='<mark>'.$word.'</mark>';
    }

    $text = str_ireplace($wordsArray, $markedWords, $text);

    //right trows results
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: @mishu he just noticed that. His solution is to not replace in a loop but with an array at once. I like it. +1

Comment: Well just tested it and strange enough having a result (created for testing) with the word mark on it, and searching for mark did not corrupted the output... So probably this is the answer to go...

Comment: Very nice, I just came across another issue, although nothing to do with @Nick answer. Take again the example "Tales Of An Ancient Empire" The word Ancient will be marked the first An, and the rest of the word will be kept unhighlighted... I imagine this is a whole new problem... Anyway accepted answer.. Thanks

Comment: You could order the wordsarray by size (biggest first) before the foreach loop. This should do it.

Comment: Surely something like <mark><mark>An</mark>cient</mark> wouldn't be an issue? I know it's not the cleanest of markup and it should probably be avoided if possible, but it'd highlight them the same. I'm also not sure if my solution really fixes your problem either. using an array won't replace them all at once, it replaces left to right, so if your search is for "words mark" it'll run into the same issue (if both words were found to highlight). Think the only way round this would be regex...unless someone else knows something I don't?

Comment: see my comment .. on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838227/php-sort-an-array-by-the-length-of-its-values

Comment: @Flo @Nick I found that sorting the order of the array works well for me. Made quite a few tests and almost all of them are good. Only found one bug Where you search for "Ma Mark". Where it breaks the `<mark>`. Although i don't see such a search being done ;) lol

Answer (score 1):

You could instead replace it with a temporary string that will no be searched (eg. {{{ and }}}) like this:

```
$text = str_ireplace($word, "{{{".strtoupper($word)."}}}", $text, $count);
```

After marking all your hits you can just do a simple replace of the temporary strings to your span tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use a preg_replace with negative look-behind instead:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!<sp)(?<!<\/sp)(an)/i', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $text);
```

The first look-behind is for starting span tags and the second for ending tags. Possibly you can combine them into one, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
$text = preg_replace("|($word)|", "<span class=\"highlight\">".strtoupper($word)."</span>", $text, $count);
```