# Sorting a multi-dimensional array according to length in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have a function that finds all the possible combinations of an array:

```
function combination($array) 
{    
    $results = array(array());

    foreach ($array as $element)
        foreach ($results as $combination)
            array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $combination));

    return $results;
}
```

This returns a multidimensional array and it works.

If I try to print the array, I use this:

```
foreach (combination($set)  as $combination)
{
    print join("\t", $combination) . "  - ";
}
```

For: `$set = array('s','f','g');`

The output is: `- s - f - f s - g - g s - g f - g f s -`

Now what I cant figure out is how can I sort the combinations according to length in a way where the output becomes:   `- g f s  - g s - g f - f s - g - s - f -`

Comment: Have a look at this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838227/php-sort-an-array-by-the-length-of-its-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use 'usort' for this:

```
function sortByLength($a, $b) {
    return count($b) - count($a);
}

$result = combination($set);

usort($result, 'sortByLength');
```

you could also just use 'sortByLength' as an anonymous function, instead of defining it, if you use this only once:

```
$result = combination($set);

usort($result, function($a, $b) {
    return count($b) - count($a);
} );
```

Comment: Thats right but Im not trying to sort $set, I am trying to sort combination($set).

Comment: just save the result of combination($set) in a variable - i edited the example for you

Comment: your script works with a 1 dimensional array, combination($set) is a multidimensional array

Comment: can you post the array structure of the multidimensional array? does the sorted array have to stay multidimensional, or one-dimensional?

Comment: it doesnt have to remain multidimensional, and the array structure is obvious in the question, look at the function combination

Comment: for that, you basically only need to change strlen() to count() - it even would stay multidimensional that way. I'll edit it in.