# Sorting array based on array length

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

What's the best way in PHP to sort an array of arrays based on array length?

```
array (size=3)
   0 => 
      array (size=3)
         0 => string '1' (length=1)
         1 => string '2' (length=1)
         2 => string '3' (length=1)
   1 => 
      array (size=6)
         0 => string '1' (length=1)
         1 => string '2' (length=1)
         2 => string '3' (length=1)
         3 => string '4' (length=1)
         4 => string '5' (length=1)
         5 => string '6' (length=1)
   2 => 
      array (size=4)
         0 => string '1' (length=1)
         1 => string '2' (length=1)
         2 => string '3' (length=1)
         3 => string '4' (length=1)
```

I need sorting it based of size of array
Become like this:

```
array (size=3)
   0 => 
      array (size=6)
         0 => string '1' (length=1)
         1 => string '2' (length=1)
         2 => string '3' (length=1)
         3 => string '4' (length=1)
         4 => string '5' (length=1)
         5 => string '6' (length=1)
   1 =>     
      array (size=4)
         0 => string '1' (length=1)
         1 => string '2' (length=1)
         2 => string '3' (length=1)
         3 => string '4' (length=1)
   2 => 
      array (size=3)
         0 => string '1' (length=1)
         1 => string '2' (length=1)
         2 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Can someone help me to create function to sorting. thank you

Comment: The best way is to use `usort`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852964/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-according-to-length-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [usort](http://php.net/usort).

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    return (count($b) - count($a));
}
usort($array, 'cmp'); //$array is your array 
$arrayAfterSort = $array;
```