# php order array in two ways

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to order the elements of an array by the following two ways:

- Sort by key length (smallest should go first) - [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838227/php-sort-an-array-by-the-length-of-its-values)
- Max value should go first

To sort by key length I use this:

```
    function sortByLength($a,$b){
      if($a == $b) return 0;
      return (strlen($a) < strlen($b) ? -1 : 1);
    }

    uasort($deals_tag,'sortByLength');
```

And the array is sorted that way:

```
Array
(
 [/merchantProductFeed] => 1
 [/merchantProductFeed/merchant] => 1
 [/merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod/text] => 158
 [/merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod] => 158
)
```

I want it to be sorted like this:

```
Array
(
 [/merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod] => 158
 [/merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod/text] => 158
 [/merchantProductFeed] => 1
 [/merchantProductFeed/merchant] => 1
)
```

Notice that first the array is sorted by key length and then by max value.

I don't know how to do that.

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You can simplify `sortByLength()`: `return strlen($a) - strlen($b);`

Comment: `uasort` is sort by value, not by key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated:** you can use [array_mulitsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). try

```
$k= array();
$v = array();

foreach($deals_tag as $key => $value){
    $k[] = $key;
    $v[] = $value;
}

array_multisort($v, SORT_DESC, $k, SORT_ASC,  $deals_tag);
```

Comment: I tried that and I get [/merchantProductFeed] => 1, [/merchantProductFeed/merchant] => 1, [/merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod] => 158, [/merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod/text] => 158

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you so much for this! Really gave me a helping hand!

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be a little bit overhead but a different way to sort things is by using a (temporary) DB, I use it personally if I need some "hardcore" sorting so here it is...

```
<?php
$p = new PDO("sqlite::memory:");
$p->exec("CREATE TABLE a (k varchar(255),v int)");

$p->exec("INSERT INTO a (k,v) VALUES('/merchantProductFeed',1)");
$p->exec("INSERT INTO a (k,v) VALUES('/merchantProductFeed/merchant',1)");
$p->exec("INSERT INTO a (k,v) VALUES('/merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod/text',158)");
$p->exec("INSERT INTO a (k,v) VALUES('/merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod',158)");

$st=$p->query("SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY length(k) DESC,v DESC");
print_r($st->fetchAll());
?>
```

I donÄt know how long your string is, in this example I used varchar(255) if it is longer you should use TEXT.

Comment: I do appreciate that you took the time to write an answer but in my case the string /merchantProductFeed/merchant/prod is saved in the database as an entire string and then I break it into parts by using `explode`.