# php - sorting array (loading values from database) from shortest to longest

Tags: php, sorting

I have next code:

```
<select>
    <?php foreach ($values as $info) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $info['id'] ?>" <?php echo $value == $info['id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $info['text'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

i loading values from database! 
And have next results:

```
    <option value="1">Jacksonville (Florida)</option> 
    <option value="2">Florida reg.</option> 
    <option value="3">Florentia</option> 
    <option value="9999">Florida</option> 
    <option value="5">Miami (Florida)</option>
```

how to do: on the top were the shortest results for 'text':

Florida 
Florentia 
Florida reg. 
Miami (Florida) 
Jacksonville (Florida)

```
        <option value="9999">Florida</option> 
        <option value="3">Florentia</option>
        <option value="2">Florida reg.</option> 
        <option value="5">Miami (Florida)</option> 
        <option value="1">Jacksonville (Florida)</option>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php): `usort($values, function($a, $b) { return strlen($a['text']) > strlen($b['text']); } );`

Comment: just in case, if you are loading values from database, you can change query to get results order by the column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Sort an array by the length of its values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838227/php-sort-an-array-by-the-length-of-its-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), as [answered here in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838227/php-sort-an-array-by-the-length-of-its-values).

```
function sort($a,$b){
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
}

usort($array,'sort');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using mysql(i) or similar to populate the `$values`, so if this is the case, you can do it at the database level by using a query similar to;

```
SELECT name
FROM testing_table 
ORDER BY LENGTH(name)
```

To see this in action, you can create a database table like this;

```
CREATE TABLE `testing_table` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) COMMENT='' ENGINE='InnoDB';
```

With some test data;

```
INSERT INTO testing_table (name) VALUES ('eeeee'),('bb'),('ccc'),('a'),('dddd');
```

A link to see it all in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/558f9/2