# Can anyone explain, why my sorting doesn't work properly?

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I wanted to use `usort()` function to sort array by it's values' lengths.
Here is my function:

```
$max_min_length = function ($a, $b) {

if (strlen($a) > strlen(b))
    return 1;
elseif (strlen($a) < strlen(b))
    return -1;
else
    return 0;
};

$array = ["abcd","abc","de","hjjj","g","wer"];
usort($array, $max_min_length);
print_r($array);
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => g [1] => abcd [2] => abc [3] => hjjj [4] => de [5] => wer )
```

I cannot understand, why it doesn't sort properly. Am I missing something?
I've looked at [PHP: Sort an array by the length of its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838227/php-sort-an-array-by-the-length-of-its-values) and their solutions work just fine. I just want to know, why does this happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: error reporting would have signaled an undefined constant b notice.

Comment: You need to turn on display_errors and error_reporting, otherwise you'd have been told about your `b`, which is undefined constant being treated as a string. so `strlen('b')` is ALWAYS `1`

Comment: The error is pretty clearly visible to me, and has been pointed out by other users already. When erros like this occur, you will have been displayed an error. Please [edit] your question to show us the exact error that you are seeing.

Comment: After I've added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` multiple `Notice ...` messages have appeared.
Thank you very much for your answers. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typo for "b" without "$"

replace code with:

```
if (strlen($a) > strlen($b))
    return 1;
elseif (strlen($a) < strlen($b))
    return -1;
else
    return 0;
};
```

After it your code will work fine :)

Comment: Good ol' PHP squelching the error as to not make you feel bad. ;)

Comment: @Neil: php will happily tell you about the problem, but most people like coding with the "lalalalalala can't hear you" finger-in-ears method, and have all error reporting turned off.

Comment: Yeah, sometime it is good to switch on error reporting :D

Comment: ...or the OP turns around and says *"Oh sorry, that was a typo; the `$` is in there.... blah blah blah"*. Seen that all too often. Let's hope it isn't the case here ;-)

Comment: @VladimirGilevich Спасибо мужик ))

Comment: @MarcB My mistake then. I plead ignorance of php.  ;)