# Sort preg_match_all by named group size

Tags: php

I wrote a regular expression that parses a JS file and returns all the named functions and breaks it up into 3 parts, you can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/sXrHLI/1

I am analyzing the results and hoping to sort by the string length of the `functionBody` but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is how I am capturing it:

```
$js = file_get_contents('scripts.js'); 
$regex = "/function\s+(?<functionName>\w+)\s*\((?<functionArguments>(?:[^()]+)*)?\s*\)\s*(?<functionBody>{(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))*+})/";
preg_match_all($regex, $js, $jsFunctions);
dd($jsFunctions);
```

This spits out an array like this:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(54) "function smallFunction(arg) {
    BodyofSmallFunction
}"
    [1]=>
    string(62) "function mediumFunction(arg, arg2) {
    BodyofMediumFunction
}"
    [2]=>
    string(80) "function largeFunction(arg, arg2, arg3=4) {
    BodyofLargeFunction, extra text
}"
  }
  ["functionName"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "smallFunction"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "mediumFunction"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "largeFunction"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "smallFunction"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "mediumFunction"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "largeFunction"
  }
  ["functionArguments"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "arg"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "arg, arg2"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "arg, arg2, arg3=4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "arg"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "arg, arg2"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "arg, arg2, arg3=4"
  }
  ["functionBody"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "{
    BodyofSmallFunction
}"
    [1]=>
    string(27) "{
    BodyofMediumFunction
}"
    [2]=>
    string(38) "{
    BodyofLargeFunction, extra text
}"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "{
    BodyofSmallFunction
}"
    [1]=>
    string(27) "{
    BodyofMediumFunction
}"
    [2]=>
    string(38) "{
    BodyofLargeFunction, extra text
}"
  }
}
```

Now I want to sort by the `functionBody` size (they already appear sorted, but are really just in the order I had them in) but none of the code examples I can find using array_multisort or array_map seems to quite fit my array that PHP automatically builds. I would have loved to have had them in more of a consolidated tree format, but that wasn't my choice.

```
function sort_by_length($arrays) {
    $lengths = array_map('count', $arrays);
    asort($lengths);
    $return = array();
    foreach(array_keys($lengths) as $k)
        $return[$k] = $arrays[$k];
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838227/php-sort-an-array-by-the-length-of-its-values

Comment: I had looked at that earlier and the issue I see is that there are 3 functions in the array, but there are 7 items in the array. They are stored as full matchs, then by name, then args, then the body, and then stored again by their names. All of them would have to be sorted at the same time to keep them relational to each other, right?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out using a method described here: https://www.codepunker.com/blog/3-solutions-for-multidimensional-array-sorting-by-child-keys-or-values-in-PHP

```
$js = file_get_contents('scripts.js'); 
$regex = "/function\s+(?<functionName>\w+)\s*\((?<functionArguments>(?:[^()]+)*)?\s*\)\s*(?<functionBody>{(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))*+})/";

preg_match_all($regex, $js, $jsFunctions);

$num_results = count($jsFunctions[3]);

function sortRegex(){
  global $jsFunctions, $num_results;

  for( $j=0;  $j <= $num_results; $j++){
    unset($jsFunctions[$j]);
    if ( strlen($jsFunctions["functionBody"][$j]) < strlen($jsFunctions["functionBody"][$j-1]) ){
      $functionBody = $jsFunctions["functionBody"][$j];
      $jsFunctions["functionBody"][$j] = $jsFunctions["functionBody"][$j-1];
      $jsFunctions["functionBody"][$j-1]=$functionBody;

      $functionName = $jsFunctions["functionName"][$j];
      $jsFunctions["functionName"][$j] = $jsFunctions["functionName"][$j-1];
      $jsFunctions["functionName"][$j-1]=$functionName;

      $functionArguments = $jsFunctions["functionArguments"][$j];
      $jsFunctions["functionArguments"][$j] = $jsFunctions["functionArguments"][$j-1];
      $jsFunctions["functionArguments"][$j-1]=$functionArguments;
      sortRegex();
    }
  }

}
sortRegex();
```

You could now loop over it again and combine the items into a nested tree format if you wanted to.

```
$refinedJS = array();

for( $j=0;  $j < $num_results; $j++){
$refinedJS[$j]= array(
  "functionName"=>$jsFunctions["functionName"][$j],
  "functionArguments"=>$jsFunctions["functionArguments"][$j],
  "functionBody"=>$jsFunctions["functionBody"][$j]
  );
}
print_r($refinedJS);
```

This will bring back the results like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [functionName] => smallFunction
            [functionArguments] => arg
            [functionBody] => {
    BodyofSmallFunction
}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [functionName] => mediumFunction
            [functionArguments] => arg, arg2
            [functionBody] => {
    BodyofMediumFunction
}
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [functionName] => largeFunction
            [functionArguments] => arg, arg2, arg3=4
            [functionBody] => {
    BodyofLargeFunction, extra text
}
        )

)
```

Comment: As an interesting sidenote, the largest function in jQuery is called `defaultPrefilter` and is 4535 in length :)