# Sorting flat associative array by values DESC, then by whitelisted keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array, custom-sort

I have the following array:

```
$array = [
    'z' => 2,
    'd' => 1,
    'a' => 2,
];
```

Now I would like to sort by the value (integer) and then sort by the key based on whether it is in this allowlist:

```
$allowlist = ['a', 'd'];
```

So I did the following:

```
arsort($array);
uksort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return in_array($a, $allowlist) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

But that returns:

```
[d]: 1
[a]: 2
[z]: 2
```

What I really want is to sort the values first and then if there is a tie breaker, sort the key based on whether its in that allowlist which should result in this:

```
[a]: 2
[z]: 2
[d]: 1
```

Comment: I think the sorts should keep the current order in case of a tie, so maybe doing the `uksort` first and then the `arsort` solves the problem. The sort that is more important should come last.

Comment: "I think the sorts should keep the current order in case of a tie" --- if only it's stable. PHP does not guarantee (before 8.0) built-in sorts to be stable.

Comment: Oh yes and so my solution doesn't work.

Comment: Read the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: What about if you have a key of `x` with a value of `2`, how should that sort relative to `z`? They both have the same value, and neither are on the allowlist

Answer (score 2):

You can use `uksort` which will give you the keys, and you can pass the `$array` into your sort function to get access to the value.

```php
$array = [
    'a' => 2,
    'z' => 2,
    'd' => 1
];
$allowlist = ['a', 'd'];

uksort(
    $array,
    static function($a, $b) use ($array, $allowlist) {
        if($array[$a] === $array[$b]) {
            return in_array($a, $allowlist) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return $array[$b] <=> $array[$a];
    }
);
```

This was inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65315474/231316

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/toZIt

Comment: @mickmackusa, the accepted answer on that page was essentially RTFM which we kind of did back then, but I no longer think is a good answer. That’s why I’m not voting it as a duplicate. Your answer had zero ups (but one now!) and does what the OP wants. For arrays of consequence, it might have performance problems, but “working” needs to come before that. Out of curiosity, how would you solve this? The two arrays method with multi sort?

Comment: Personally, although I like using `fn` with auto capture, the double `in_array` with rocket is a speed bump in my brain that I have to think about for a bit. I’m not saying it is bad in anyway, in my codebases I would just need a comment to explain what is going on, whereas the one I posted is more self documenting to me. But if you post that as an answer, I’d be glad to upvote it!

Comment: Consider the extensibility of this technique.  If the OP ever wants to extend the sorting rules to implement another tiebreaker, then with my cascading rule syntax, there is just one more line of code and no nested `if` structure.  It is a style preference, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making as few evaluations as possible and as few function calls as possible.

This principle makes `array_multisort()` the top choice for this task.  [`usort()` will make more iterated calls than `array_map()` (which has a linear time complexity) and that will put a drag on performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71878764/2943403)

Flipping the whitelist array will allow it to be used as a lookup array.  Because `false` comes before `true` when sorting in an ascending direction, check that the key is NOT found in the lookup.

- Sort by values descending (param1: `$array` and param2: `SORT_DESC`)
- Sort by existence in the whitelist array (param3)
- The final parameter will be affected by all sorts which occurred earlier.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/m0N3Q))

```
$array = [
    'z' => 2,
    'd' => 1,
    'a' => 2,
];
$allowlist = array_flip(['a', 'd']);

array_multisort(
    $array,
    SORT_DESC,
    array_map(fn($k) => !isset($allowlist[$k]), array_keys($array)),
    $array
);

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a' => 2,
  'z' => 2,
  'd' => 1,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is using the `array_flip` function on the keys. This give the `uksort` a value it can compare:

```
$array = [
    'a' => 2,
    'z' => 2,
    'd' => 1,
    'e' => 1,
];
$allowlist = array_flip(['a', 'e', 'd']);

uksort(
    $array,
    static function($a, $b) use ($array, $allowlist) {
        if ($array[$a] === $array[$b]) {
            if (!key_exists($a,$allowlist) || !key_exists($b,$allowlist)) {
                return 0;
            }
            return $allowlist[$a] <=> $allowlist[$b];
        }
        return $array[$b] <=> $array[$a];
    }
);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($array,1).'</pre>';
```

result in :

```
Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [z] => 2
    [e] => 1
    [d] => 1
)
```